# FPC protocol to HDMI for pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Can you please help understand how I can connect 39pin FPC LCD to raspberry pi3?
I guess it is not possible to connect LCD directly to pi display connector.

Is there FPC to HDMI converter module, which I can buy and than connect LCD to HDMI output of pi3?

If not, than what other solutions exists?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is strictly for programming questions - maybe try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Than why there is raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3 tags exists here?

Comment: Those are for questions about Raspberry Pi *software* - yours relates to a physical, *hardware* connector. I don't make the rules, I'm just trying to help you be more likely to get an answer...